# PHP contact form doesn't work (3)

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm creating php-ajax-jquery contact form following this tutorial http://www.sanwebe.com/2011/12/making-simple-jquery-ajax-contact-form

Looks like it works on localhost (it shows message that email sent), but it doesn't work on server.

Could you please help me with few questions:

1. does email sends when trying on localhost?
2. how to fix problem with server, why nothing happens after pushing submit button?

this is index text

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Simple Ajax Contact Form</title>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#Submit").click(function() { 
       
     var proceed = true;
        //simple validation at client's end
        //loop through each field and we simply change border color to red for invalid fields  
  $("#contact_form input[required=true], #contact_form textarea[required=true]").each(function(){
   $(this).css('border-color',''); 
   if(!$.trim($(this).val())){ //if this field is empty 
    $(this).css('border-color','red'); //change border color to red   
    proceed = false; //set do not proceed flag
   }
  });
       
        if(proceed) //everything looks good! proceed...
        {
   //get input field values data to be sent to server
            post_data = {
    'user_name'  : $('input[name=name]').val(), 
    'phone_number' : $('input[name=phone2]').val()
   };
            
            //Ajax post data to server
            $.post('contact_me.php', post_data, function(response){  
    if(response.type == 'error'){ //load json data from server and output message     
     output = '<div class="error">'+response.text+'</div>';
    }else{
        output = '<div class="success">'+response.text+'</div>';
     //reset values in all input fields
     $("#contact_form  input[required=true], #contact_form textarea[required=true]").val(''); 
     $("#contact_form #contact_body").slideUp(); //hide form after success
    }
    $("#contact_form #contact_results").hide().html(output).slideDown();
            }, 'json');
        }
    });
    
    //reset previously set border colors and hide all message on .keyup()
    $("#contact_form  input[required=true], #contact_form textarea[required=true]").keyup(function() { 
        $(this).css('border-color',''); 
        $("#result").slideUp();
    });
});
</script>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<!--<link href="/zvonoq/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />-->

</head>

<body>
<div class="form-style" id="contact_form">
    <div class="form-style-heading">Please Contact Us</div>
    <div id="contact_results"></div>
    <div id="contact_body">
        <label><span>Name <span class="required">*</span></span>
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" required="true" class="input-field"/>
        </label>
        <label><span>Phone</span>
            <input type="text" name="phone2" maxlength="15"  required="true" class="tel-number-field long" />
        </label>
        <label>
            <span>&nbsp;</span><input type="submit" id="Submit" value="Submit" />
        </label>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

this is contact_me.php

```html
<?php
if($_POST)
{
 $to_email    = "myemail@gmail.com"; //Recipient email, Replace with own email here
 
 //check if its an ajax request, exit if not
    if(!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) AND strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) != 'xmlhttprequest') {
  
  $output = json_encode(array( //create JSON data
   'type'=>'error', 
   'text' => 'Sorry Request must be Ajax POST'
  ));
  die($output); //exit script outputting json data
    } 
 
 //Sanitize input data using PHP filter_var().
 $user_name  = filter_var($_POST["user_name"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
 $user_email  = filter_var($_POST["user_email"], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
 $country_code = filter_var($_POST["country_code"], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
 $phone_number = filter_var($_POST["phone_number"], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
 $subject  = filter_var($_POST["subject"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
 $message  = filter_var($_POST["msg"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
 
 //additional php validation
 if(strlen($user_name)<4){ // If length is less than 4 it will output JSON error.
  $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Name is too short or empty!'));
  die($output);
 }
 if(!filter_var($phone_number, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT)){ //check for valid numbers in phone number field
  $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Enter only digits in phone number'));
  die($output);
 }
 
 //email body
 $message_body = $message."\r\n\r\n-".$user_name."\r\nEmail : ".$user_email."\r\nPhone Number : (".$country_code.") ". $phone_number ;
 
 //proceed with PHP email.
 $headers = 'From: '.$user_name.'' . "\r\n" .
 'Reply-To: '.$user_email.'' . "\r\n" .
 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
 
 $send_mail = mail($to_email, $subject, $message_body, $headers);
 
 if(!$send_mail)
 {
  //If mail couldn't be sent output error. Check your PHP email configuration (if it ever happens)
  $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Could not send mail! Please check your PHP mail configuration.'));
  die($output);
 }else{
  $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'message', 'text' => 'Hi '.$user_name .' Thank you for your email'));
  die($output);
 }
}
?>
```

Comment: Is the email service running on your host?

Comment: @JayBlanchard not sure. how to check it?

Comment: @angelzzz email does not work on localhost,, and for server, please check with your hosting wether they provide email feature or not...

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this was made way more complicated than it has to be. Change you're contact_body to a `<form>` (don't forget to change the closing tag)

You can then simply do this using jQuery to send the form

```
<?php
  $.post("www.someSite.com/someScript.php",
      $("#contact_body").serialize())
  .error(function(){
      //Show alert for not being able to make a connection
  })
  .success(function(data){
        var response = JSON.parse(data); //Get json object from response text 
        if(response..type != error){
            //Show some error
        }else{
           //All went well
        }
  });
```

If you click the button and nothing is happening then there is something wrong with your javascript. Open up the Web/Javascript console to check for errors